# How to Alter timestamp without timezone column to text , varchar and long in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a column named entry , it is in timestamp format .
I want to alter it to text , varchar or long  .
Can you please provide me a query .

Comment: In which format? [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) for `text` and `varchar` (in this case they'd be the same)? [Unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) for `long`?

Comment: **Never** store timestamp values in a `varchar` column. That is a **really**, really bad idea

Comment: As there is an issue , after setting the date as timestamp , it is convert to pivot and after that pivot to java . here i am loosing .SSS that's why we are thinking to convert it into varchar .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bad idea to do that, but it would work for example like this:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ALTER mycolumn
   TYPE text USING to_char(mycolumn, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS');
```